# React Native position search bar over map

Tags: reactjs, react-native

How can I position the search bar **over** the map instead of next to the map (screenshot)? I want to mimic the look and feel of the Google Maps app in mine. They have the bar above the ~ top 10% of the map.

```
<View>
        <StatusBar backgroundColor="rgba(1.0, 0, 0, 0.2)" translucent />
        <SearchBar
          ref='searchBar'
          placeholder='Find me'
          barStyle="black"
          showsCancelButtonWhileEditing={false}
        />
        <MapView
          provider={ PROVIDER_GOOGLE }
          style={ styles.container }
          initialRegion={{
            latitude: 32.815013,
            longitude: -117.273404,
            latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
            longitudeDelta: 0.0421,
          }}
        />
      </View>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Stretch the MapView to the full screen size using `flex: 1`.

Absolute position the Searchbar and set the coordinates. `position: absolute;`

Comment: To expand on vijayst's answer. I got this working like this... 

```
  <View style={{flex: 1}}>
    <MapView ... />
    <View style={{padding: 10, position: 'absolute', left: 0, top: 0, right: 0}}>
        <GooglePlacesAutocomplete
            ....
        />
    </View>
</View>
```